# JNI ERROR Didn't find class DexPathList while trying to create module for POS

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, libc

I have a project and i want to use it to create a module.
But i keep getting this error as i try to load the native file;
To be specific, its triggered on running System.loadLibrary("")
 The gradle file is right after the error log.

```
A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewGlobalRef called with pending exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.cloudpos.jniinterface.EMVJNIInterface" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.company.wazopostrial1-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.company.wazopostrial1-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.company.wazopostrial1-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:511)
    art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:469)
    art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String) (Runtime.java:-2)
    art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.doLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Runtime.java:435)
libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 8698 (y.wazopostrial1)
```

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    sourceSets {
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                cppFlags ""
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni/','src/main/jniLibs/'] } }
    externalNativeBuild{
        ndkBuild{
            path 'jni/Android.mk'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

If interested in reproducing the issue kindly inbox github handle.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the C++ code that does the failed `FindClass` call, as well as the Java class it's trying to find.

Comment: @Michael, never mind, issue was because the file location i had specified for the native library required admin permissions. Fixed the issue and everything works fine now.